# Angularjs add constant value to directive's templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got constant in module :

```
angular.module('identicaApp.common', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies'])
    .constant('ROOT_PATH', '/static/angular/identica/')
```

so I want to use it in another directive, in templateUrl attribute, something like this:

```
angular.module('identicaApp.registration.player', ['identicaApp.common'])
    .component('registerPlayer', {
        templateUrl: ROOT_PATH + 'registration/register_player/register_player.html',
```

so how can i do this?

Comment: I think constants can be injected into controller, directive as usually any other pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In component `templateUrl` function you can have dependencies injected and use it to form `templateUrl`.

**Code**

```
angular.module('identicaApp.registration.player', ['identicaApp.common'])
  .component('registerPlayer', { 'registration/register_player/register_player.html',
    templateUrl: function(ROOT_PATH){ //<-- add dependency in function
       return ROOT_PATH + 'registration/register_player/register_player.html',
    },
    ...
  })
```

Check [**here**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition) in doc where clearly mentioned that `templateUrl` is injectable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
angular.module('identicaApp.registration.player', ['identicaApp.common'])
.component('registerPlayer', {
    templateUrl: function(ROOT_PATH) {
     return   ROOT_PATH + 'registration/register_player/register_player.html'
    } 
});
```

Inject your constant in `function ()`.

Comment: component should assigned to object, not function

Comment: Better update/delete an answer, otherwise you might end up getting more downvote .